# Creating a Morse Code translator for my programming class,having troubles with the output

Tags: java, for-loop, morse-code

this is my first post on this platform ,im kinda new to this java programing and also not that good at english :p

My teacher asked for a morse code translator that does morse to letters and vice versa

Here's the code i came up with:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Morse2 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
 String[] letras = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l",
                  "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", 
                  "y", "z"};                  
 String[] MORSE = {
 ".-" ,"-...","-.-.","-.." ,"." , 
 "..-.","--." ,"....",".." ,".---", 
 "-.-" ,".-..","--" ,"-." ,"---" , 
 ".--.","--.-",".-." ,"..." ,"-" , 
 "..-" ,"...-",".--", "-..-","-.--", 
 "--.."}; 
System.out.println("Insira uma frase em codigo morse para uma traducao para texto ou vice-versa");
Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
String frase =in.nextLine();
String resp="";

frase=frase.toLowerCase();
String[] paraletras=frase.split("");
String[]paraMorse=frase.split(" ");
for(int i=0;i< paraletras.length;i++){
    for(int j=0;j< letras.length ;j++){
     if (paraletras[i].equals(letras[j])){
    resp=resp+ MORSE[j]+" ";}
    }
}
for(int k=0;k<paraMorse.length;k++){
     for (int l=0;l<MORSE.length;l++){
          if(paraMorse[k].equals(MORSE[l])){
    resp=resp+letras[l]+ " ";}}
    }

System.out.print(resp);}

    }
```

The class compiles fine but im having some issues with my output,more specifically the order of the output:

e.g My input " a b -.- c "
    What i wanted ".- -... k -.-."
    What i got ".- -... -.-. k"
I believe that's because i used 2 for cycles instead of 1 but i cant really tell how to do it.Would apreciate some help
Also when the user writes an impossible character like "*" im suppossed to put an "?" in that position and im also strugling on that i dont know if i should use a if else cycle or what

Please help me and thank you everybody ^^

Comment: Hello there Joao, did you post your question on the portuguese StackOverflow? Also, I recomend adding the tag "Java", so people can help you more...

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are correct. It is because you run your loops sequentially.

You need one loop over your input, then check if one piece of input is a letter - take translation from letters array, if it is a MORSE take from Morse array.

Actaully arrays are not the best approach. It is much easier to use one Map where letter will be a key, MORSE will be a value.

then code may look like:

```
 public static void main(String... args) {

    String[] letras = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r",
            "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z" };
    String[] MORSE = { ".-", "-...", "-.-.", "-..", ".", "..-.", "--.", "....", "..", ".---", "-.-", ".-..", "--",
            "-.", "---", ".--.", "--.-", ".-.", "...", "-", "..-", "...-", ".--", "-..-", "-.--", "--.." };
    System.out.println("Insira uma frase em codigo morse para uma traducao para texto ou vice-versa");


    Map<String, String> decodeMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

    for (int i=0; i< letras.length; i++)
    {
        decodeMap.put(letras[i], MORSE[i]);
    }

    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    String frase =in.nextLine();
    String resp = "";

    frase = frase.toLowerCase();
    String[] paraletras = frase.split(" ");     
    for (int i = 0; i < paraletras.length; i++) {
        boolean gotValue = false;
        for (Entry<String, String> decodeEntry: decodeMap.entrySet()) {             
          if (decodeEntry.getKey().equals(paraletras[i]))
          {
            // it is a letter print its MORSE
            resp += decodeEntry.getValue();
            gotValue = true;
            break;
          } else if (decodeEntry.getValue().equals(paraletras[i]))
          {             
            // it is a MORSE - print its letter
            resp += decodeEntry.getKey();
            gotValue = true;
            break;
          }
        } 
        if (gotValue)
        {
          resp += " ";
        }
    }
    System.out.print(resp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to evaluate every group or chars to guess if it is morse or not.

```
Example:
First group: 'a'
  is morse -> no
  is a letter -> yes -> then convert to morse
Second group: 'b' 
  is morse -> no
  is a letter -> yes -> then convert to morse
Third group: '-.-'
  is morse -> yes -> then convert to letter
```

This code could be more efficient, but I think it is easy to understand. I hope this help you to improve your programming skills.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Morse2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] LETRAS = { 
                "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", 
                "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", 
                "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", 
                "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", 
                "y", "z" };

        String[] MORSE = {
                ".-", "-...", "-.-.", "-..", ".", "..-.", 
                "--.", "....", "..", ".---", "-.-", ".-..", 
                "--", "-.", "---", ".--.", "--.-", ".-.", 
                "...", "-", "..-", "...-", ".--", "-..-", 
                "-.--", "--.." };

        System.out.println("Insira uma frase em codigo morse para uma traducao para texto ou vice-versa");
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        String frase =in.nextLine();
        String resp = "";

        frase = frase.trim().toLowerCase();
        String[] chars = frase.split(" ");

        for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {

            String group = chars[i];

            String newChar = null;

            for (int j = 0; j < LETRAS.length; j++) {
                if (LETRAS[j].equals(group)) {
                    newChar =  MORSE[j];
                    break;
                }
            }   

            if (newChar == null) {
                for (int j = 0; j < MORSE.length; j++) {
                    if (MORSE[j].equals(group)) {
                        newChar =  LETRAS[j];
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (newChar == null) {
                System.out.println("Group not found: "+group);
                continue;
            }
            resp += newChar + " ";

        }
        System.out.print(resp);
        in.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry to be such a noob,but probably is also because ive been here since 8 hours ago but why is this code giving me only the morse code to the letter 'a' a couple times?

Comment: This code is OK. The code you have modified has 2 mistakes. Look at the if statements inside the loops. You have close the if statements. Due to this, the loop doesn`t work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to be such a noob,but probably is also because ive been here since 8 hours ago but why is this code giving me only the morse code to the letter 'a' a couple times?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Morse2 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
 String[] abecedario = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l",
                  "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", 
                  "y", "z"};                  
 String[] MORSE = {
 ".-" ,"-...","-.-.","-.." ,"." , 
 "..-.","--." ,"....",".." ,".---", 
 "-.-" ,".-..","--" ,"-." ,"---" , 
 ".--.","--.-",".-." ,"..." ,"-" , 
 "..-" ,"...-",".--", "-..-","-.--", 
 "--.."}; 
System.out.println("Insira uma frase em codigo morse para uma traducao para texto ou vice-versa");
Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
String frase =in.nextLine();
String resp="";
frase=frase.toLowerCase();
String[] palavra=frase.split(" ");
for(int i=0;i< palavra.length;i++){
    String letra=palavra[i];
    String novochar="";

    for (int j=0;j<abecedario.length;j++){
        if (abecedario[j].equals(letra));
        novochar=MORSE[j];
        break;

    }
    if(novochar==""){
        for (int j=0;j<MORSE.length;j++){
        if (MORSE[j].equals(letra));
        novochar=abecedario[j];
        break; 
    }
    }

    if(novochar==""){
        novochar="?";
        continue;

    }   
    resp=resp+novochar+" ";
    }
    System.out.println(resp);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is because you did not make proper `if` in the loops with `j`. Look: `if (abecedario[j].equals(letra));` - does nothing you closed it. Then `novochar=abecedario[j];` is always  `abecedario[0]` and `for` breaks after it immediatelly. So... you forgot to do it as: `if (abecedario[j].equals(letra)) {
        novochar=MORSE[j];
        break; }`          - same for `if` in the second `for` loop